# Como rellenar un Vuetify DataTable con axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify

Mi tabla no se completa,
si logro obtener los datos pero no puedo mostrarlos

```
<template >

  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="itemss"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.cus_identity_card}}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.cus_first_name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.cus_last_name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.cre_career }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.cus_mail}}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.suc_name }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.int_interpretation}}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.cui_percetage }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.int_career }}</td>
    </template>

  </v-data-table>


</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          { text: 'Registro',
            align: 'left',
            sortable: true,
            value: 'registro'
          },
          { text: 'Carnet', value: 'itemss.cus_identity_card' },
          { text: 'Nombre', value: 'itemss.cus_first_name' },
          { text: 'Apellidos', value: 'itemss.cus_last_name' },
          { text: 'Carrera', value: 'cre_career' },
          { text: 'Correo', value: 'cus_mail' },
          { text: 'Sede', value: 'suc_name' },
          { text: 'Aptitud principal', value: 'int_interpretation' },
          { text: 'Porcentaje (%)', value: 'cui_percetage' },
          { text: 'Carreras sugerentes', value: 'int_career' }
        ],
        itemss: [
          {
            cus_identity_card:"",
            cus_first_name:"",
            cus_last_name:"",
            cre_career:"",
            cus_mail:"",
            suc_name:"",
            int_interpretation:"",
            cui_percetage:"",
            int_career:"",
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    mounted(){

  this.$http.get(`report/`)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.data[0])
    this.itemss = response.data.data[0];
    console.log("xd")
    console.log(this.itemss.cus_identity_card )
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
  });
},

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Podes confirmar que en itemss queda lo que vos queres? o solamente no pasa nada? si es asi, la respuesta de Shaz es la correcta

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema típico de contextos, cuando estás en axios (then), this no es lo mismo que estando fuera de este:

```
mounted(){
  var self = this;

  this.$http.get(`report/`)
  .then((response) => {
    self.itemss = response.data.data[0];
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
  });
},
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda pero en el main importe el AXIOS
y pues no tengo problemas con este

`import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import Axios from 'axios'

const HTTP = Axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://*****'})

Vue.cxcel from 'vue-json-excel'onfig.productionTip = false;

Vue.prototype.$http = HTTP;`

Comment: Al parecer no entendiste la respuesta, tan solo compara el código que pusiste en tu pregunta y el de esta respuesta (no hablo solo de la indentación).

Comment: @MoisésOchoa la respuesta sí resuelve tu pregunta.